# Differences between excludedDocuments and documentVisibility

Tags: docusignapi

Looking at the official [documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/#core-recipient-parameters/), I don't understand the difference between those 2 data points:

> excludedDocuments     No  Array of Strings    Specifies the documents that
> are not visible to this recipient. Document Visibility must be enabled
> for the account and the enforceSignerVisibility property must be set
> to true for the envelope to use this.

> documentVisibility    No  documentVisibility  A complex type that
> specifies which documents are visible to this recipient.

Do both of those properties achieve the same behavior ? If no, what is the difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Frederic, you can think of Document Visibility as account wide feature. You can control wide access to documents. You can read about the details in this [guide](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-document-visibility). Exclude Documents is even granular access, where you can restrict signers to see documents which are allowed by the wider visibility permission. Visibility on account level is controlled under Sender settings. This extensive [guide](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-sending-settings) has section document visibility explaining different levels